# php/sql how to shift rows according to missing data?

Tags: php, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a database and some rows have been deleted.
The problem is that the row entries are numbered such that:

1. pie
2. bananas
3. cake
4. eggs

(example of entries with food)
If I delete a row, say I remove bananas, then the database looks like this:

1 pie

3 cake

4 eggs

How can I make it so the data base automatically shifts to fill in these gaps? Example of the new data base:

1. pie
2. cake
3. eggs

I want this to occur automatically. I don't think this is too hard but im a complete beginner at php stuff so I need someone to tell me what I need to do.

Comment: Add numbering on PHP side...

Comment: You can fill in the gaps, but your application code shouldn't care about gaps. Perhaps give us more information about why gaps are a problem for you application.

Comment: You should't do that.  The `id`s identify the rows of the table.  In a well-designed database, they are used for foreign key relationships -- and might be used over time too (say in database backups).  Don't change them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these IDs have a unique index on them, there are lots of reasons to not restructure your IDs but the main one, in my opinion, is that makes it difficult to rely on your IDs for any amount of time.

Think about it like this. You 4 rows of data which have unique IDs.

```
+----+---------+
| ID |  Name   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | pie     |
|  2 | bananas |
|  3 | cake    |
|  4 | eggs    |
+----+---------+
```

You give your users a link to each item.

1. `http://my-application.com/item/1` (points to pie)
2. `http://my-application.com/item/2` (points to bananas)
3. `http://my-application.com/item/3` (points to cake)
4. `http://my-application.com/item/4` (points to eggs)

Now, you delete row 3.

```
+----+---------+
| ID |  Name   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | pie     |
|  2 | bananas |
|  4 | eggs    |
+----+---------+
```

And restructure your IDs to 1,2,3

```
+----+---------+
| ID |  Name   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | pie     |
|  2 | bananas |
|  3 | eggs    |
+----+---------+
```

Now, a user with an older bookmark comes along and visits `http://my-application.com/item/3`, expecting to get *cake*, but instead gets *eggs*. When in fact, they should get `404, cake doesn't exist`.

In addition to the above, you have to update all related tables (foreign keys) which would have a cascading effect.

This could introduce other issues such as table locks, not to mention being a terribly slow and unwieldy process.

---

Instead, don't use the ID for numbering in your application code. Use it as it is intended, to isolate a unique row of data.

Use your application code (PHP, C#, JS, ...) to generate gap-less numbers.

```
+----+---------+
| ID |  Name   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | pie     |
|  2 | bananas |
|  4 | eggs    |
+----+---------+

<ol>
foreach (item in items) {
    <li>Item<li>
}
</ol>

1. pie
2. bananas
3. eggs.
```

If you need gap-less numbers from your DB, look into using *row_number*.

Comment: Excellent reply, was very helpful and eye-opening seeing the potential problems with reassigning unique indexes, especially the related tables and the cascading effects with the ID's.

While these concerns are valid, the ID's AND the 'food types' are unique... so think of the food as a username.

With this is there still no good way to reorganizer the ID's? I'm not particularly worried about a cascading effect or dependent tables since those are related via the 'username' and not the index number.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to reset the IDs? Just because you don't like the gaps, or is there a practical reason? For what it's worth, gaps in auto-incremented IDs are completely normal and do not affect performance. It is abnormal to restructure IDs. My recommendation is to not restructure them unless you have a very good reason. But, your question doesn't give enough information about your requirements so I am just guessing for now.